# Hibernate DTD not loading from the classpath, the jar is there, still getting FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, configuration

I am getting

```
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative
location [hibernate.cfg.xml] Offending resource: ServletContext
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
[/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml]; nested exception is
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
[org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd] cannot be opened
because it does not exist
```

this is the dependency I am using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

importing hibernate file in spring using import-

```
<import resource="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

Jar is there in the maven dependencies but still cannot load DTD

Comment: Why not just delete the DOCTYPE? Does it define entities?

Comment: Just want to mention [XML Catalogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog) as alternative to external DTDs. - `"classpath:///org..."` or single `/`?

Comment: Have you tried `<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">` ? This also works offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the Spring application context.

So, instead of having:

```
<import resource="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

You need to make sure the hibermate.cfg.xml is located somewhere in your jars.

If you're using Maven, just place it in the following path:

```
${project.home}/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

This way, the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file will be included in the module jar during the build time.